# How to make a table or DataFrame from dtype=object?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, sentiment-analysis

I would like to show how the predictions are made in a table or DataFrame.

I tried to put X_test, y_test and predictions (predictions = model.predict(X_test)) into a DataFrame to show which reviews are positive or negative predicted.

```
import pandas as pd

predictions = model.predict(X_test)
df_prediction = pd.DataFrame({
    'X_test': [X_test],
    'y_test': [y_test],
    'prediction': [predictions]
})
df_prediction.head()
```

Variable "X_test" (Name: review, Length: 4095, dtype: object) looks like:

15806    ['tire', 'gauges', 'kind', 'thing', 'makes', '...

541      ['like', 'said', 'title', 'review', 'say', 'pr...

...

Variable "y_test" (Name: label, Length: 4095, dtype: object) looks like:

15806    positiv

541      positiv

...

Variable "predictions" looks like:

array(['positiv', 'positiv', 'positiv', ..., 'positiv', 'positiv',
'positiv'], dtype=object)

At the moment I got a DataFrame with all Data in the first line but I need as a table with all lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `x_test`, `y_test` and `predictions` are lists, then you could just do this:

```
df_prediction = pd.DataFrame({
    'X_test': x_test,
    'y_test': y_test,
    'prediction': predictions
})
```

Also, `df_prediction.head()` will print the first 5 rows of the dataframe. You could use `print(df_prediction)` or just `df_prediction` (for formatted output in Jupyter Notebook) to see the entire data.